# Used flutter_svg package but SVG files are not rendering in bottomnavigation bar

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

Hi I know that Flutter still doesn't support SVG files so I used flutter_svg package, but for some reason, the svg file is not rendering the SVG file I want to use.

What I want is use my custom SVG files as Icon in the bottomnavigation bar items.

> I want to use SVG icons so that I can easily change their colors when they are inactive or active (selected)

I call it like this:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg_home.svg"),
  title: Text("Home"),
  activeIcon: Icon(Icons.category, color: Color(0xFFEF5123)), 
),
```

Answer (score 5):

Fixed it

```
  height: 20.0,
  width: 20.0,
  allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
```

I'm beginning to slowly fall in love with flutter

Answer (score 2):

Use property activeIcon also inside BottomNavigationBarItem

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
    icon,
    height: 20.0,
    width: 20.0,
  ),
  activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
    icon,
    height: 20.0,
    width: 20.0,
    color: Colors.pinkAccent,
  ),
  label: title,
);
```

SVG color changing will work now. Now use label instead of text.